# zooming in silverlight

Tags: silverlight, zooming

I have created a 3D structure(basically an image) dynamically using kit3D.However,I wanted to zoom only a small segment of the whole structure.My entire image is loaded altogather at a time,so I am not considering using deep zoom.
Is there anyway where I can zoom only a part of a dynamically generated image in silverlight??

Thank you,
Ramya

Comment: Actually i am creating 6 phases of the cube with these images and this in the will be a single 3D structure.I have to zoom only a part of one face.

Anybody has some idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use a MultiScaleTileSource for that. It's a callback based system - it requests Deep Zoom tiles from a function you implement when the user zooms or pans.

Here's some [sample code](http://weblogs.asp.net/jeff/archive/2008/10/26/conquering-deep-zoom-part-2-serving-tiles-custom-multiscaletilesource.aspx), and here's a [full working example that pulls map tiles dynamically from Virtual Earth](http://www.codeplex.com/deepearth).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Scale RenderTransform  to increase the size of the image, then use a clip to only show one part of it, thus giving the effect of zoom.

Alternatively you can use a [ViewBox from the Silverlight toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/Wiki/View.aspx?title=Silverlight%20Toolkit%20Overview%20Part%201&ANCHOR#Viewbox)

Answer (score 0):

This [example](http://weblogs.asp.net/palermo4/archive/2008/04/14/video-magnify-a-portion-of-a-photo-using-silverlight-1-0.aspx) may be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

there is an example of use silverlight 3 and Virtual Earth on  http://www.silverenlightenment.com/